# org.ros.rosjava Jar Messages files Do Not update

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
My message jar files at at /.ros/rosjava/lib/org.ros.rosjava.my_msgs-0.0.0.jar. I have the problem that when I change the message (add one more field) and rosmake the message. It is compiled but the jar files are not updated. I even removed the org.ros.rosjava.my_msgs-0.0.0.jar from /.ros/rosjava/lib/ even then it does not generate new jar file for my_msgs.
Did anyone have the same problem, how can I fix it??
Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12415/org.ros.rosjava-jar-messages-files-do-not-update/) by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2011-12-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a known issue. See http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/detail?id=62

As a workaround, the easiest (although time consuming) thing to do is `rm -rf ~/.ros/rosjava` and then rebuild. It is also possible to selectively remove everything from `~/.ros/rosjava` (i.e. use grep and find) that has to do with you package and then rebuild which is faster.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0